# Error to connecting Azure database to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure

My client give me access to their Azure database, adding firewall rules they added my IP address in a firewall rule when I connect to it using its server name Username and with password SQL Server gives error.

[image: see error image]

Comment: Hard to tell from your screen shot, but are you using `taskhandoverserver 1.database.windows.net` with a space in its name between `taskhandoverserver` and `1`?

Comment: no there is no space

Comment: Which authentication do you use?

Comment: Can you open a Command Prompt or a PowerShell prompt and `tracert taskhandoverserver1.database.windows.net` successfully? The error message in the screenshot suggests that you cannot resolve the DNS name to an IP address, so I'd expect a tracert to fail with something like `Unable to resolve target system name ...`

Comment: I didn't open command prompt or powershell.

Comment: I try it different systems but it's give same error

Comment: I am using "SQL Server Authentication"

Comment: and Server type Database Engine

Comment: Please post the error as text rather than a picture. (I can't see pictures they are blocked)

Comment: _I didn't open command prompt or powershell_ You are being asked to do this to help troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Closing and downvote since OP will not enrich question with the error message,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried to connect to the SQL server, I got the same error as mentioned below:

[image]

In my case, the server name had a space between "dbservere" and ".database.windows.net." Even though the server name was correct, the space prevented me from connecting to the SQL server. To resolve the issue, I went to the Azure portal and copied the name from the portal itself, as mentioned below:

[image]

After trying to connect using the above server name and credentials, it connected successfully without any errors, as shown below:

[image]

Along with that, check the following options while connecting to the SQL server:

- Make sure outbound traffic over port 1433 is allowed by your network's firewall.
- Make sure you have provided the correct details of the SQL server.

For more information, you can refer to this [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-connection).

Comment: how can I allow?
Make sure outbound traffic over port 1433 is allowed by your network's firewall.

Comment: I don't have any space in my server name or username and password

Comment: Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-connection) once.